# error in HNOCs (OMNeT++ ) while running provided examples

Tags: omnet++

Hi all, I am trying to run HNOCs written in OMNeT++ for NoCs. I wanted to compare the simulation accuracy of the provided examples of this framework. Unfortunately, this is giving some weird (maybe for me, as I am a novice to this) error. The error is happening for all the examples.

```
<!> Error: Cannot assign parameter 'numPorts': Parameter refers to itself in its assignment (did you mean 'parent.numPorts'?) -- at /home/xxxx/Desktop/OMNETPP/omnetpp-6.0.1/HNOCS/src/routers/hier/Router.ned:49 -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) Mesh.router[0].port[0] (id=194), during network setup
running iteration 96 ...
```

Can anyone please point out what this is and guide me?

Thank you.

Best regards
Manikanta

I tried understanding but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Open `HNOCS/src/routers/hier/Router.ned` and change the line:

```
numPorts = numPorts;
```

into:

```
numPorts = parent.numPorts;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.